# Ignore bracket in csv file python

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a python script for a friend that:

1. takes a CSV of photos she's been cataloging that has the name of the photos in an ordered list
2. finds the image files on the filesystem
3. matches the files in the csv with files on the system
4. copies the images on the filesystem to a folder with a figure name in the order the files appear in the CSV

So essentially, it does:

---

INPUT: myphoto1.tiff, mypainting.jpeg, myphoto9.jpg, orderedlist.csv

OUTPUT: fig001.jpg, fig002.tiff, fig003.jpeg

---

This code is going to run on a mac. This works fine except we ran into an issue where some of the files (all by the same photographer) have 1 bracket in them, e.g.

```
myphoto[fromitaly.jpg
```

This seems to break my regular expression search:

The relevant code:

```
orderedpaths = [path for item in target for path in filenames if re.search(item, path)]
```

Where filenames is a list of the photo files on the system and target is the list from the CSV. This code is supposed to match the CSV file name (and it's subsequent order in the list) to the filename to give an ordered list of the filenames on the system.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "renameimages.py", line 43, in <module>
    orderedpaths = [path for item in target for path in filenames if re.search(item, path)]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

I tried or considered:

1. Changing the filenames/csv, but this isn't scalable and ideally her
   department will be using this script more in the future
2. Investigating treating the files as "raw" -- but it didn't seem like
   that was possible for input from CSV
3. Deleting the [ character from the input, but the problem is that
   then the input won't match the actual files on the system.

I suppose I should mention I only suspect this was the issue: by printing out the progress of the code, it appears as if the code gets to the CSV item with the bracket and errors.

Comment: Try replacing all instances of `[` with `\[`.

Comment: consider doing `item.replace('[', '\[')`

Comment: @karthikr this will probably fix this specific problem, but not the general one.

Comment: Your problem is that you do not escape the regex meta characters. Why are you using regex for this anyway? What's in `target` exactly? Can we see some example `item`s. Is it just `myphoto[fromitaly.jpg`?

Comment: In order for you to see this traceback, the file name `myphoto[fromitaly.jpg` or another unbalance brace would need to be part of `item`. It is during the compilation of the pattern you are getting the exception. This is probably an error in your code.

Comment: @drewk this is an error of mixing code and data, basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code is the part where you buld a regular expression using a user input, without sanitizing it. You should not do that.

I believe you don't need to use RE at all. you can find matching string using `if item in path` or `path.endswith(item)` or something like that.

The best option is to use your library:

```
from os.path import basename
orderedpaths = [ ... if basename(path) == item]
```

If you insist on using REs, you should escape your input using [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
orderedpaths = [path for item in target for path in filenames
                 if re.search(re.escape(item), path)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your latter suggestion did the trick:

orderedpaths = [path for item in target for path in filenames
                 if re.search(re.escape(item), path)]

Comment: @dantiston, it is the last thing I would do... please try using other ways, at least for production code.

Comment: Also: I tried your first suggestion (with os.path.basename), and it didn't catch as many as the regular expression. However, I did some more testing with the escaped RE and it seems to work well.

Comment: +1, but: Why are you using `ntpath` instead of `os.path`? Especially on a Mac? Also, is the `path[:-3]` bit meant to remove extensions? If so, you'd want `path[:-4]`—but you don't want that, either, because it will fail on any extension that isn't 3 letter long (like half the OP's actual examples).

Comment: @abarnert - I saw in another question here that it's more portable, but if you are commenting, I assume I understood wrong. About the rest - you are right. (I didn't really recommend that - it was only an example).

Comment: @Elazar: It's not really about "portable". `os.path` handles native paths for your platform, so it's appropriate for when you're dealing with paths on the local machine (i.e., most use cases). `ntpath` handles Windows-style paths (with backslashes and drive letters) no matter what platform you're on, so it's appropriate if you're dealing with pathnames from a Windows machine (e.g., writing a log parser that has to run anywhere, but handles logs from a Windows server).

Comment: @Elazar: By the way, the safe way to remove extensions is `os.path.splitext(path)[0]` (or `ntpath.splitext` or `posixpath.splitext`, as appropriate).

Comment: @abarnert I understood all that. *After* I saw your comment. and you are welcome to improve my answer (or post a different one with corrections).

Comment: @Elazar: Nah, it's fine now. Your answer isn't at all confusing as it stands, and anyone who manages to get confused anyway should manage to figure things out from your comments and mine.